# Custom showMaxMin text in nvd3

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to modify some output of a normal nvd3 chart. For example, [This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pleaseteachmehowtodoit/6muZa/#base).

What I would like is to see before the bold Max/Min additional information explaining that it is the max/min, i.e:

```
`Max: 1033.88`
```

If I'm right this info is given by [showMaxMin](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/d51729c49be84added7201248b163c8376f04042/src/models/axis.js#L88) function and [axisMaxMin](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/search?q=axisMaxMin&type=Code), and bold from css in the nv.d3.css code (also in the fiddle, css line 243 ).

```
.nvd3 .nv-axis .nv-axisMaxMin text {
  font-weight: bold; /* Here the text can be modified*/
}
```

I have tried several things without success (it means I've been unable to make it work, but it can probably be solved if coded right):

- Editing css to add :before a text showing max *(Not working)*

  ```
  .nvd3 .nv-axis .nv-axisMaxMin text:before {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  { 
  content:"Max: ";
  }
  ```
- Accessing with jquery *(not working either)*

  ```
  $('.nv-axisMaxMin').each(function() {
  $(this).text("Max: "));
  });
  ```

The resulting html shows for the maximum this result:

`<text dy=".32em" y="0" x="-3" text-anchor="end" style="opacity: 1;">132.23</text>`

And I want it to be something like this:

`<text dy=".32em" y="0" x="-3" text-anchor="end" style="opacity: 1;">Max: 132.23</text>`

I think there might be several approaches, via css, via html, via js, but my newbie skills has not been enough to get to it in any way.

I would prefer not to modify source code.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I don't see any max/min information in your jsfiddle. In principle the way you're doing it is correct, but NVD3 uses transitions to initialise the graph and you need to run the code after the transition has finished.

Comment: I did not include it because I could not make it work. I am going to try it now with your advice, after the transition has finished.

Comment: What about css? How can I force css code to be executed after NVD3 transition?

Comment: Updated fiddle in the same link to show the max/min information with things I had already tried and I tried again without success.

Comment: Could you post the link to the updated jsfiddle please? And you can't execute code in CSS, it's just style information.

Comment: @Lars Kotthoff Yes, sorry for my bad programming expression. What I meant by "executing" code in CSS was to add some text to the label when styling (css lines 242-253) in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pleaseteachmehowtodoit/6muZa/#base), which is the same one that is shown at top, as I said, because the updated version was set at base. I tried to do it both ways, it is shown there. I was based on [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_before) to do it via css.

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/6muZa/3/)?

Comment: Yeah! you rock. The only point is that it is not updated when changing anything, resizing window, stacking, hiding data streams... Any solution for that? I guess that changing the source code would work adding that text inside those functions, I would prefer not to do it

Comment: This should work http://jsfiddle.net/6muZa/4/

Comment: That works with resizing. Thank you. Stacked/Grouped and Legend stil eliminate the text.

Comment: Ok, so find out what events are fired for that and hook into them. If there aren't any, you'll have to modify the source.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will work on it.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff After learning and trial-error, I'm right now like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/pleaseteachmehowtodoit/6muZa/13/), working on mouseover after changing labels. I've been unable to do it for the Controls and Legend. Is there a defined dispatch that works all the time? Like a synonymous to  *dispatch.on('always')*

Comment: I don't think there is unfortunately.